# Service runs app is closed

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-service

I have an application in Xamarin.Forms and I have developed a service that works only when the application is open or minimized.
I've added some logs and the service keeps running even with the application closed, but part of my code that is on Portable does not run.

Code MainActivity

```
var alarmIntent = new Intent(context.ApplicationContext, typeof(Receiver.AlarmReceiver));
var broadcast = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context.ApplicationContext, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.NoCreate);
if (broadcast == null)
{
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context.ApplicationContext, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    var alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
    alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime(), 15000, pendingIntent);
}
```

Code Alarm Receiver

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        var backgroundServiceIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(ServiceBackground));
        context.StartService(backgroundServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

Code Service

```
[Service]
public class ServiceBackground : Service
{
    private const string TAG = "[ServiceBackground]";
    private bool _isRunning;
    private Context _context;
    private Task _task;

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        _context = this;
        _isRunning = false;
        _task = new Task(RunServiceBackground);
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        if (!_isRunning)
        {
            _isRunning = true;
            _task.Start();
        }
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    private void RunServiceBackground()
    {
        Log.Info(TAG, "StartCommandResult");

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Info(TAG, "init background portable");
                var serviceOrdersSvc = new ServiceOrdersService();

                serviceOrdersSvc.BackgroundExecute()
                                .ContinueWith(itemResult => {
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemResult.Result))
                                    {
                                        Log.Info(TAG, "itemResult");

                                    }
                                });
            }
            catch (Android.OS.OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                Log.Info(TAG, $"ex msg: {ex.Message} | s: {ex.StackTrace}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Info(TAG, $"ex msg: {ex.Message} | s: {ex.StackTrace}");
            }
            finally
            {
                StopSelf();
            }

        });
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        base.OnDestroy();
    }
}
```

Code portable (This part that does not work)

```
public async Task<string> BackgroundExecute()
{
    //insert sqllite
    await LogService.InsertLogAsync("init - BackgroundExecute");

    //get sqllite
    var list = await BackgroundTaskRequest.GetListAsync();
    var rtnBackground = "";

    if (list != null && list.Count > 0)
    {
        LogService.InsertLogAsync("list count: " + list.Count.ToString());

        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                //send information web-api
            }
        });
    }

    LogService.InsertLogAsync($"end rtn: {rtnBackground}");

    return rtnBackground;
}
```

Is the something i am missing here?

Comment: 1st) You have two `InsertLogAsync` that are not being `await`, like the first one in your example... 2nd) You are calling out to `BackgroundTaskRequest .GetListAsync` and that is within the method `BackgroundExecute`, this can not be dependent upon having `Xamarin.Forms` app init'd and should be totally free of Forms code, so LogService, BackgroundTaskRequest, etc... should be independent classes/methods that you are instancing within the Service itself (they could be static or instanced and held at the Android Application level so they could be "shared" by Forms and your Service)

Comment: Also you are starting the Service as sticky when it should not be, you are starting up the Service via the AlarmManager and after BackgroundExecute returns you are not self-stopping the service. This would not be considered a Sticky service. Also on Oreo and above, since it is not a foregrounded service, Oreo+ will send your application into idle mode, basically calling StopSelf on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks. I changed my code and just left the line to write the record in SQLLite. I've changed the methods to static and it still does not work.
Questions, in my case my code needs to be in the Android project layer? And which my method needs to return what StartCommandResult information?